# How to remove asynchronized function outputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really not sure what to name this question, so I gone for that.

In conclusion, I want my JS to work line by line, but I got (I guess) an asyncronized result.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gx5x8sbf/

**JQuery(slim downed version):**

```
$.fn.extend({
    addContent: function(a) {
        var start = "<div>",
            end = "</div>",
            $this = $(this);
        $this.append(start+a);
        if (a == "special") {
            $this.addSpecial(c,d,e,f,g); //Many parameters
        }
        $this.append(end);
    },
    addSpecial: function(c,d,e,f,g) {
        //quite some work done here
        var b = "result";
        $(this).append(b);
    }
})
```

**The output I want when I run `$("#this").addContent("special")`:**

```
<div>specialresult</div>
```

**The actual output:**

```
<div>special</div>result
```

What to do? Please help!

I can't add `return $(this)` in `addSpecial()` to queue a function, because I would add if else statements in `addContent()` other than is `a == "special"` so that would not be a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` automatically closes tags.  So `$this.append(start+a);` creates `<div>special</div>`.

An alternative is to use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.extend({
        addContent: function(a) {
            var div= $('<div>').appendTo(this);
            div.append(a);
            if (a == "special") {
                div.addSpecial(); //Many parameters
            }
        },
        addSpecial: function() {
            //quite some work done here
            var b = "result";
            $(this).append(b);
        }
    })
    $("#this").addContent("special");
})
```

### Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

<s>The problem here isn't async/sync</s> but that $this refers to the original element you called addContent on, not your dynamically generated div. Why not try something like this?

```
$.fn.extend({
    addContent: function(a) {
        var start = "<div>",
            end = "</div>",
            $this = $(this);
            var toAppend = start+a;
            if (a == "special") {
                toAppend += $this.addSpecial(c,d,e,f,g); //Many parameters
            }
            toAppend += end;
            $this.append(toAppend);
    },
    addSpecial: function(c,d,e,f,g) {
        //quite some work done here
        var b = "result";
        return b;
    }
})
```

Comment: It IS the original element I want to alter but can't i append elements on the way? please explain. :/

Comment: if `addSpecial()` doesn't alter a `$(this)`, I wouldn't need it in a `$.fn.extend()`

Comment: Never mind, you're right. I can't explain that behavior. Is there any reason you can't construct fully the content you wish to append and then append in one shot?

Comment: Uh-oh, someone got a better answer faster than you, but I really wanted to credit you too, because you both think different ways... :/ I'll give you a +1